# Some USB drives not showing in BIOS

Tags: usb, boot, bios

I have a GA-MA790FXT-UD5P motherboard. I have an old USB drive that it will boot from just fine. I have two (identical) newer ones, but they will not boot. I found out that the newer ones aren't even recognized in the BIOS under the list of recognized devices. They will, however, work fine in other machines. Any idea what might be going on?

Comment: Are the newer USB drives larger than 2GB? Is the old one 2GB or smaller? Best case, you may just need to update your BIOS.

Comment: Some motherboard bios software will only enable a couple of USB sockets during bios/bootup. Any chance you're using different USB sockets during these comparison tests?